# How to create a view that can display multiple objects?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that looks like this:

```
struct CardView: View {
    let item: Items

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("\(item.name)")
                .font(.headline)
                .accessibilityAddTraits(.isHeader)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("\(item.description)", systemImage: "questionmark.square.dashed")
            }
            .font(.caption)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var item = Items.abilityScores[0]
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(item: item)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

(`Items.abilityScores` is a list of `Items` that I'm generating in the class file. I can show you if needed.)

I want to reuse this view for several different objects of various types.

There are a few possible ways that I could see this going:

1. I make a base class for `Item`, and then pass it to a bunch of other classes that have more properties/vars/whatever. I doubt I can do this.
2. I make each class individually, even though they're all going to be very similar in implementation/usage, and make a separate view for each of them.
3. Something else? Maybe make the parameter `AnyObject` and give them all the same field names, and then do something to like, check if the values are there or something before trying to display them?

Is #1 even possible? Or am I resigned to #2 and creating the same view over and over for different objects?

Comment: Look up protocols and/or inheritance and generics as long and the objects have something in common you can share. Ideally something more specific than AnyObject since AnyObject won’t have any real value for display

Comment: @loremipsum I'm familiar with protocols, but the issue returns to "Can I make the view require a protocol as the input that allows me to pass a class that inherits it instead?"

Comment: Possible solution: a ViewModel. A ViewModel struct that can be initialized by each of yours types, and you put their each value needed to be shown.

Comment: Yes, AnyObject would require a class. You can use either a protocol or a base class

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks -- that's helpful. If my protocol has a name property and a description property, but then one of the structs that implements it also has a "ShortName" property, is it possible to put that in the view as well if it is a field that exists? My gut says "still no" because the compiler is going to freak out but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You’ll have to cast the object to the type that has ShortName with a conditional. Basically only show ShortName if the object is TypeThatHasShirtName

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137211/using-same-struct-for-two-different-listdata/66137790#66137790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
protocol ItemProtocol {
    func name() -> String
    func description() -> String
    func optionalThing() -> String?
}

struct Item1: ItemProtocol {
    var n: String
    var d: String
    var t: String
    func name() -> String {
        n
    }
    func description() -> String {
        d
    }
    func optionalThing() -> String? {
        t
    }
}

struct Item2: ItemProtocol {
    var n: String
    var d: String
    func name() -> String {
        n
    }
    func description() -> String {
        d
    }
    func optionalThing() -> String? {
        nil
    }
}


struct CardView: View {
    let item: ItemProtocol

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("\(item.name())")
                .font(.headline)
                .accessibilityAddTraits(.isHeader)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("\(item.description())", systemImage: "questionmark.square.dashed")
                if let optionalThing = item.optionalThing() {
                    Label("\(optionalThing)", systemImage: "questionmark.square.dashed")
                }
            }
            .font(.caption)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

With:

```
let viewController = NSHostingController(rootView: CardView(item: Item1(n: "Name1", d: "Description1", t: "Optional Thing")))
```

[image]

With:

```
let viewController = NSHostingController(rootView: CardView(item: Item2(n: "Name2", d: "Description2")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- I have something similar to this working. My issue arises when `Item1` has a property that is not required by the `Item` protocol -- For example, I have a struct that has a "short" property. I'm struggling now with how to implement that functionality into the view, i.e. if the struct has the property then show it, if that make sense?

Comment: You could add a method to the protocol that returns an optional _thing_ and if it's non-nil then display it, else display a default value or display nothing.

Comment: @phroureo Edited.

Comment: Ah, so I would still need to put the `OptionalThing` in the protocol and pass the `nil` to each of the children? That's what I had assumed but was trying to avoid/see if there was a better way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @phroureo There might well be a better way; my Swift is rusty :~|

Comment: I figured this out thanks to your help -- essentially it was `let title: String /n if let variableName = item as? Item1 { title = variableName.OptionalThing } else { title = item.Name }` + adding the `return` before the first `vstack`